# lastInsertId = 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert into my database which works fine but the LastInsertId always comes up as 0, any ideas?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO players_results (matchweek_id, matchweek, game_id, username, homeresult, awayresult, goals, submit, matchweek_session) Values (:matchweekid, :matchweek, :gameid, :username, :homeresult, :awayresult, :goals, :submit, :matchweeksession)');

          for ($gi = 1; $gi <= 10; $gi++) {
            $stmt->execute(array(
            ':matchweekid' => '1',
            ':matchweek' => 'Matchweek 1',
            ':gameid' => $gi,
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':homeresult' => NULL,
            ':awayresult' => NULL,
            ':goals' => NULL,
            ':submit' => 'n',
            ':matchweeksession' => 'open'   
          ));
          $id = $db->lastInsertId('member_id');
        }
```

Comment: Yes everything seems to work ok on my end, except the 0

Comment: why you add member_id into $db->lastInsertId ?

Answer (score 3):

//Change

```
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

to

```
$id = $stmt->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Dis you get your answer @ryan